# LiveReload on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, livereload, package-control

LiveReload seems not to be working on sublime text 3 when I download it from the package control.

I found this link (https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2/tree/devel) on github, but there's no info on how to do it on windows (I'm on W7). Is it possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: *"seems not to be working"* is very vague. Please [edit] your question to include **exactly** what you've done, including any browser plugins or server-side Javascript includes, whether or not you're using the [standalone program](http://livereload.com/), and any other pertinent information to help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: I've installed LiveReload with the package control on ST3. I've also installed the extension on chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by kslstn and NEKEY are right, but are missing a crucial step if you are working on a local project.

So, after installing LiveReload on sublime text and installing the chrome extension and enabling both of them, make sure, in the chrome extensions page, to enable access to file URLs.

[image: Visual description of what to do]

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of trial and error I've managed to get LiveReload working on Windows 8 + Sublime Text 3!

1. Get the files from the devel branch with the [link](https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2/tree/devel).
2. Put those files in your Packages directory: `C:\Users\[YOUR USER NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
3. Restart Sublime Text 3
4. Enable the 'Simple reload' plugin. You have to repeat this step every time you restart Sublime Text. To do this:

   - Open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
   - Type LiveReload
   - When 'enable/disable plugins' is highlighted, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you have the browser plugin installed, changes to your files should now immediately be shown upon save. You may also decided to insert the JS snippet, which you can do very easily through the command palette!

I've seen comments about Windows Firewall blocking the localhost with LiveReload. I haven't really had this issue, but I disabled the Firewall the first time, just to be sure. When I re-enabled it and restarted LiveReload, Windows Firewall showed a dialog asking me to refuse or allow the plugin to make connections. So now everything works fine even with the firewall up.

It's actually pretty simple.

Comment: oh wow, wasn't expecting an answer after so long!

I'll have to try it out!

Comment: I just tried this with ST2, and when I click the icon in Chrome to enable LiveReload it gives me this message: `Could not connect to LiveReload server. Please make sure that a compatible LiveReload server is running. (We recommend guard-livereload, until LiveReload 2 comes to your platform.)`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Package Control to install LiveReload for Sublime Text 3, it doesn't work correctly.

This method works though:

1. Navigate to https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2/tree/devel and download the whole devel branch by clicking on "Download ZIP".
2. Extract contents of the archive to: "%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages" and open that Packages folder.
3. Rename "LiveReload-sublimetext2-devel" folder to "LiveReload", this is an important step to make it work (name has to match).
4. Restart Sublime Text 3, Ctrl+Shift+P, "LiveReload: Enable/Disable Plugins", enable SimpleReload, ENJOY the amount of time saved by not switching to browser every time you change a line of code.

P.S. You do need to get the LiveReload Google Chrome plugin, just search for it on Google Chrome Extensions Web Store.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download extension for your browser I've found these:

Safari : http://download.livereload.com/2.0.9/LiveReload-2.0.9.safariextz

Firefox : http://download.livereload.com/2.0.8/LiveReload-2.0.8.xpi

Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei

More info Here https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LiveReload.

If I understand it correctly, it works via Sockets, so you can't do anything without browser extension.

Comment: I've installed LiveReload with the package control on ST3. I've also installed the extension on chrome.